# polymer indexedDB egg inside chicken

Tags: javascript, polymer, indexeddb

How can I tell the chicken to wait for the async egg database to do a chicken function `read()` in polymer?

Here my `loadChanged` does not work?

```
<polymer-element name="my-chicken">
    <template>
        <style>
            p {font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif; padding:10px;}
        </style>

        <p>Loading...</p>

        <my-egg iLoad="{{load}}" iDB="{{db}}"></my-egg>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-chicken', {

            load:false,
            db:null,
            out:null,

            write:function(){
                this.db.result.transaction(["store"], "readwrite").objectStore("store");
                var customerData = [
                    {muts: "Bill", qty: "1"},
                    {muts: "Donna", qty: "1"},
                ]
                for (var i in customerData){db.put(customerData[i])}
            },

            remove:function(k){
                this.db.result.transaction(["store"], "readwrite").objectStore("store");
                db.delete(k)
            },

           read:function(tx){
              var f =function(e) {
                var cursor = e.currentTarget.result;
                if (cursor) {
                    console.log(cursor.key)
                    var br=document.createElement('br')
                    var span=document.createElement('span')
                    span.innerHTML=cursor.key
                    span.onclick=function(){remove(cursor.key)}
                    this.out.appendChild(span)
                    this.out.appendChild(br)
                    cursor.continue()
                }
              }.bind(this)
              this.out.innerHTML=""
              var req = tx.openCursor()
              req.onsuccess = f
              console.log('hello')
            },

            ready:function(){
                this.out=this.shadowRoot.querySelector('p')
            }

            loadChanged:function(){
               console.log('hello')
               var tx=this.db.result.transaction(["store"], "readwrite").objectStore("store");
               this.read(tx)
            }    
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="my-egg" attributes="iDB iLoad">
    <script>
        Polymer('my-egg', {
            iDB:null,
            iLoad:false,
            ready:function(){

                var load=function(){
                  this.iLoad=true
                  console.log('iLoad',this.iLoad)
                }.bind(this)

                var request = indexedDB.open("my-database",1);
                request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
                    var db = e.currentTarget.result
                    var store = db.createObjectStore("store", {keyPath: "muts", autoIncrement:false})
                    console.log('db upgrade', 'v'+db.version)
                }
                request.onerror = function(e) {
                    console.error('db error ',e)
                }
                request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                    var db = e.currentTarget.result
                    console.log('db setup', 'v'+db.version, 'OK')
                    load()
                }
                this.iDB=request
            },
            drop: function () {
                this.iDB.result.close()
                var req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(this.iDB.result.name);
                req.onsuccess = function() {console.log("Deleted database successfully")}
                req.onerror = function() {console.log("Couldn't delete database")}
                req.onblocked = function() {console.log("Couldn't delete database due to the operation being blocked")}
            }
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Which comes first? my-chicken or my-egg?

Comment: my egg is in the chicken

Comment: But is there a chicken in the egg?

Comment: no `this.iRead` refers to the database itself instead of the chicken. So no chicken inside the egg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer? You don't wait. Have your code simply set up your element so that if nothing's written yet, the state that's visible to the user makes sense. Then simply update it once your "egg" has finished doing its thing. If that update triggers a counter update, then that's perfectly fine and you have that reflected in your user-visible state again.

Also: cute as it is, that's the worst element naming for the purposes of getting a useful answer. The comment thread is pretty much a total derail because of it =)

Comment: I edited the question. I am stuck at the load watcher `this.iLoad` now. Don't know how to get at the other `this` from the egg element.

Comment: just... alias it, like you'd do anywhere else? `var self = this; var load=function(){ self.iLoad=true; }`. Or, alternatively, use the special new-function-with-explicit-context generating `bind()` function to make sure "this" points to what you need it to, with `var load=function(){ this.iLoad=true; }.bind(this)`

Comment: Ok really close now :) only the final part has this problems left :) tried `readf:function(e){...}.bind(this)` see edit

Comment: never mind I put the function in the other function :) Victory at last, Thanks